# How to calculate (+ or - or * or /) using php variable?

Tags: php

Why this 2 code not echo same result ?

On first code echo `*57`, But i want to echo `35` like on second code.

How can i do that ?

```
<?PHP
$fomular = "*5";
$x = "7";
$res = $fomular."".$x;
echo $res;
?>

<?PHP
echo 5*7;
?>
```

Comment: You are treating them as string remove double quotes

Comment: `$res = $formular + $x;`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues.

In your example

```
...
$res = $fomular."".$x;
...
```

Is the same as saying

```
...
$res = "*5".""."3";
...
```

So that explains the "*53" been echoed/

```
...
$res = $fomular + $x;
// or
$res = $x + $fomular;
...
```

Will return 12 as it will not evaluate the "*" but rather add the numbers.

You could use eval( ... ) but it is evil and would really advise against it.

```
...
echo eval( "5*" . "7" . ";");
...
```

So your best bet, if you really want to echo the result, would be to write your own function to parse the 2 strings and do the operation.

Comment: A plus from me. If they want evil, oh i mean `eval()` that be it. Why not!

Answer (score 0):

```
$formular = 5;
$x = 7;
$res = $formular * $x;
echo $res;
```

. (dot) in php is a string concatenating operator! if you try to use it with any type of variables, it converts they to string and put together. Sample: $x = 5 . 7 -> $x = '57'; but, if you use any kind of mathematicals operators (*, /, +, -), php will convert both operands to numeric form (float or int), then execute your formula and give a result $x = 5 * 7; -> $x = 35; 
**In short: use only mathematicals operators for executing formulas, not a dot.** (sory for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you use .(dot) operator it appends the two variables.

You have to use code like below to get the desired output

```
$formular = 5;
$x=7;
$res=$formular * $x;
echo $res;
```

Comment: I think the OP is given the strings "*5" and "7" and wants the result of the operation.